# How to create custom enrolment plugin in moodle-3.7?

Tags: moodle

How to create a custom enrollment plugin in Moodle-3.7?

Answer (score 6):

Well, let's imagine we want to create a new enrolment method plugin called "myenrol".

1. Create a folder within the directory `enrol` called `myenrol`.
2. Within `enrol/myenrol` create the file `version.php`. This file contains essential information about your plugin name and current version (it is used by Moodle to track your plugin version and the need to run any upgrading methods). Example:

```
<?php

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$plugin->component = 'enrol_myenrol'; // Full name of the plugin (used for diagnostics)
$plugin->release = '0.1.0';
$plugin->version = 2019072900; // The current plugin version (Date: YYYYMMDDXX)
$plugin->requires = 2018120300; // Requires this Moodle version
$plugin->maturity = MATURITY_ALPHA;
```

3. Within `enrol/myenrol` create the file `lib.php`. This is (usually) the most important file of any enrolment method plugin, since here you will define the methods that handle your "enrol" instances, for example: you could define the methods other plugins can use to create your "myplugin enrolment instances" related to users and courses, you could define the permission checks to allow/forbid the creation/removal of those instances and so on. The minimal boilerplate code you will need to write is this:

```
<?php

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

class enrol_myenrol_plugin extends enrol_plugin {


    public function use_standard_editing_ui() {
        return true;
    }

    public function edit_instance_form($instance, MoodleQuickForm $mform, $context) {
        // Do nothing by default.
    }


    public function edit_instance_validation($data, $files, $instance, $context) {
        debugging('enrol_plugin::edit_instance_validation() is missing. This plugin has no validation!', DEBUG_DEVELOPER);
        return array();
    }

    public function can_add_instance($courseid) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

4. Create the folders `lang` and `en` following the structure: `enrol/myenrol/lang/en` and finally a file `enrol_myenrol.php` within `en`. Here you need to write, at least, the string for "pluginname":

```
<?php

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$string['pluginname'] = 'My Enrolment Plugin';
```

Notice that the most important part of this kind of plugins is (usually) to expose some kind of logic (public methods) in lib.php to allow for other plugins or sub-systems to create instances of your plugin enrolment given some criteria (that your plugin must validate). For example: manual enrolment plugin allows admins/managers to create enrolment instances by selecting users one by one, cohorts enrolment plugin allows course managers to create enrolment instances by selecting cohorts (that have users listed inside), etc. Don't forget that an enrolment instance is what we use in Moodle to signify a user having some kind of access to a course (with an specific role, like teacher, student and so on).